# sql pivot row values to a single column

Tags: sql, mysql, unpivot

I have the following output from a sql query in a row. I'd like to pivot the row values to a single column labeled `id`:

```
| id | lag_1 | lag_2 | lag_3 |

| -- | ----- | ----- | ----- |

| 8  | 7     | 6     | 5     |
```

expected output:

```
id 

8
7
6
5
```

Answer (score 3):

This is known as "unpivot". Different database platforms have different methods available to accomplish. MySQL uses UNION construct to rearrange fields to rows.

```
SELECT id, 0 AS Src FROM table
UNION ALL
SELECT lag_1, 1 FROM table
UNION ALL
SELECT lag_2, 2 FROM table
UNION ALL
SELECT lag_3, 3 FROM table
```

Remove **ALL** if you don't want duplicates.

Comment: Why need to add `0`,`1`,`2`,`3`  after select column?

Comment: we can do just like this right?
`SELECT id AS id FROM your_table
UNION
SELECT lag_1 AS id FROM your_table
UNION
SELECT lag_2 AS id FROM your_table
UNION
SELECT lag_3 AS id FROM your_table`

Comment: Yes, don't have to include calculated field. Mostly included for demo as an identifier for source can often be useful. Don't have to repeat the alias field name. First SELECT line defines data type and field name.

Comment: One more thing to note: Union statement does not guarantee sequence with or without ORDER BY clause, so we need to make it a derived table which can be sorted out using ORDER BY.

Comment: Good to know but I always see ascending order.

Comment: We can test it with `insert test values(8,7,6,5),(4,3,2,1);` . Then run a straight union, the result we get is out of sequence. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c84cf/1

Comment: My test in Access query object put the values in ascending order.

Comment: @June7 I'm not sure about how it works in Access. I just tried it in ms sql server. The result does show in ascending order without ORDER BY. And if desc sorting is required, just put it at the  end. Here is the test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7c84cf/6   Maybe their products share some resemblance?